# How can I horizontally expand a combobox in jqGrid upon pull-down to display all content?

Tags: combobox, jqgrid, expand, aramex

How can I horizontally expand a combobox pull-down display?

My actual data is: `ARAMEX1234`

But the pull-down display only shows: `ARAMEX123`

I need to support the following browsers: IE 6, 7, 8.

I tested it using Firefox and it works out of the box. However, my application will be run on IE and never on FF.

Here is the code (jsp file content):

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jquery/grid.locale-ja.js" />" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/jquery/ui.jqgrid.css" />"/>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table id="rowed5"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var lastsel2;
$("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
        {name:'stock',index:'stock', width:60, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
        {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX;AR1:ARAMEX123456789"}},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}}      
    ],
    caption: "Input Types",
    resizeStop: function (newwidth, index) {
        var selectedRowId = $("#rowed5").getGridParam('selrow');
        if(selectedRowId) {
            //resize combobox proportionate to column size
            var selectElement = $('[id="' + selectedRowId + '_ship"][role="select"]');
            if(selectElement.length > 0){
                $(selectElement).width(newwidth);
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel2){
            //$(this).saveRow(lastsel2, true);
            $(this).restoreRow(lastsel2);
            $(this).editRow(id,true);

            lastsel2=id;

            $(this).scroll();

            //resize combobox proportionate to column size
            var rowSelectElements = $('[id^="' + id + '_"][role="select"]');
            if(rowSelectElements.length > 0) {
                $(rowSelectElements).each(function(index, element){
                    var name = $(element).attr('name');
                    var columnElement = $('#rowed5_' + name);
                    if(columnElement.length > 0) {
                        var columnWidth = $(columnElement).width();
                        $(element).width(columnWidth);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
var mydata2 = [
        {id:"12345",name:"Desktop Computer",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"FedEx"},
        {id:"23456",name:"Laptop",note:"Long text ",stock:"Yes",ship:"InTime"},
        {id:"34567",name:"LCD Monitor",note:"note3",stock:"Yes",ship:"TNT"},
        {id:"45678",name:"Speakers",note:"note",stock:"No",ship:"ARAMEX123456789"},
        {id:"56789",name:"Laser Printer",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"FedEx"},
        {id:"67890",name:"Play Station",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FedEx"},
        {id:"76543",name:"Mobile Telephone",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"ARAMEX"},
        {id:"87654",name:"Server",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"TNT"},
        {id:"98765",name:"Matrix Printer",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FedEx"}
        ];
for(var i=0;i < mydata2.length;i++) {
 $("#rowed5").jqGrid('addRowData',mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i added a combobox auto width adjustment based on the column size. upon resizeStop and onSelectRow. <- this is by end-user's request. And the above problem occurs. That's why I need to expand the pull-down's display width only not the combobox width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in IE. You can fix it by temporarily resizing the select input on mouseover or on focus as described in the following article: [Select Cuts Off Options In IE (Fix)](http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/)

In your specific example, the code might look like this:

```
    $("#rowed5 select").live({
        focus: function () {
            $(this).
                data("origWidth", $(this).css("width")).
                css("width", "auto");
        },
        blur: function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css("width", $this.data("origWidth"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you mean that is it not possible to expand the pull-down only not the combobox element?

Comment: Yes, The pulldown is implemented at the OS level in IE, you don't have much control of it's style or appearance.

Comment: Due to the above reason, I accept the brainpeiris' answer although the question was not answered. This is accepted as workaround. I found other solution but it uses customized combobox composed of textboxes, div element to handle the pull-down but not worth it in my case. thanks brainpeiris.